# Permanently end processes

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, xfce, process

The point is that i installed xubuntu and at one point i get on the screen one light bulb increasing and decreasing the light on the display (laptop) so i found in task manager that it is this **xfce4-power-manager** and since i kill the process it stops and in that session it's OK. so i know the solution but since this is my third day on Linux platform i don't know how to disable this process permanently so if some one know to expand and explain baby steps how can be done. 10x up front.

Comment: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/50

Answer (score 0):

You disable it from the (xfce) preferences

Click on the icon and select preferences ;)

See http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/getting-started and http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/preferences